# Rendering a view with custom mime type in Grails

Tags: grails, mime-types, content-type

I am attempting to render text for reponse in Grails with a custom contentType. My desired contentType is: *application/vnd.api+json*

I am testing with the following

```
render(contentType: "application/vnd.api+json") {
    message = 'some text'
    foo = 'bar'
}
```

which does not render throwing an exception that message is a missing property.

While the following works fine:

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {
    message = 'some text'
    foo = 'bar'
}
```

My Config.groovy has the following under json mime.type:

```
grails.mime.types = [
...
    json:          [
        'application/json',
        'text/json',
        'application/vnd.api+json'
    ],
...
]
```

My question, how to render with a custom mime-type in Grails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the `accept` header in the request set the custom content-type?

The accept header is one way for client to inform server which content-type would be acceptable for itself.

In `config.groovy` the below setting has to be set as well to use accept headers

`grails.mime.use.accept.header = true`

I would also try rendering the response in the conventional way:

```
render(contentType: "application/vnd.api+json", text: [message: 'some text', foo: 'bar'])
```

Comment: accept.header was false, enabling it did not help! I still get the  an exception "message is a missing property"

Comment: This renders fine: With text/json http://pastebin.com/0kPhTFv8 
This with application/vnd.api+json http://pastebin.com/PL0F7Pcj ends up in error

Comment: @Armand Can you try rendering this way `render(contentType: "application/vnd.api+json", text: [message: 'some text', foo: 'bar'])`

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I believe I tried this before changind the accept.header to true!