# Grails - how return hal+json content type with a custom ObjectMarshaller?

Tags: json, rest, grails

In Grails (2.3.8) how do you configure a custom JSON object marshaller and return hal+json as the content type?

I have a custom object marshaller for a class that implements `ObjectMarshaller<JSON>`.  It's registered and works fine returning application/json as the contentType.  But my custom marshaller is actually HAL-compliant, so I want to be able to indicate to clients that it's `application/hal+json`.

So far what I've tried looks something like this:
`response.contentType = "application/hal+json"
render(object as JSON)`

The above returns `application/json` as the response content-type though, so it's being overridden.

Comment: Does the answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190767/rendering-a-view-with-custom-mime-type-in-grails

Comment: I originally commented that calling `(object as JSON).toString()` allows me to set the content type...but the problem with that is the encoding is lost.  e.g. The JSON converter was configured to use UTF-8 encoding, but calling toString() on it results in the content being 8859-1 encoded, regardless of the default encoding being set to UTF-8.

Comment: But you always may reencode it through `new String (oldstr, "UTF-8")`. Or didn't I understand something?

Comment: I think I'd potentially lose content during the conversion to 8859-1, so it'd be gone when I converted it back to UTF-8.